# Can redisModule access key on different node in cluster mode

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I am trying to understand how redis module work in a cluster mode.
My settings is:

```
master1 -> 127.0.0.1:6377
master2 -> 127.0.0.1:6378
master3 -> 127.0.0.1:6379
```

All slots have been assigned to these 3 nodes automatically.
I started all 3 servers in cluster mode. Everything looks ok.

I tried to do

```
hset key1 field1 1
```

it failed and it says key1 is hashed to slot xxx which is on 6378. Fine. After tried, keys * return nothing.

I create a sample module, register a command which will take the key name, field name, value parameters. After the module has been built and I load it to all 3 servers.

All 3 server are now able to see the new command.

So far so good.

Now I try

```
mycommand key1 field1 1 on master1
```

It success!!!!

How ever, when I go
list all keys on master1, I can see key1!!!
when I try query key1, it tells me that this key1 is moved to master2 - 6378. Which is same as I tried before.

So I keep trying

```
mycommand key2 field 1
mycommand key3 field 1
```

All of them says success, and I can see all the keys from keys * command.
but when I go query on particular key, only those key that are hashed to local node are shown as expected.

Why is that?

Comment: What do you mean by "redismodule" ? do you mean the redis python client?

Comment: https://redis.io/modules